# EDGE_TPU COMPILER ERROR: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'RESIZE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR' version '3' for custom YOLO

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tpu, google-coral

I have retrained my model on Darknet and use https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3 to convert my darknet weights to h5.

I have replace relu for leaky relu for quantization purpose.
My model then has been converted to tflite model successfully by using tf-nightly.

However, I can't parse the model to edgetpu by resize nearest neighbor error.
To my understanding, resize nearest neighbor is supported in https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#supported-operations
So why did this error happened?
Any way to fix?

Here is my tflite convert code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys

def representative_dataset_gen():
    for _ in range(250):
        yield [np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, size=(1, 416, 416, 3)).astype(np.float32)]

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} <keras-model> <output-filename>")
    sys.exit(1)

model_fn = sys.argv[1]
out_fn = sys.argv[2]

# Convert and apply full integer quantization
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(model_fn)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8,
                                       tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
#converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
# Set inputs and outputs of network to 8-bit unsigned integer
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
tflite_model = converter.convert()

open(sys.argv[2], "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icl9Z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from the coral team and I'm planning on investigating the yolov3 model myself, just haven't got the bandwidth to do so yet :) 
Here are some tips from what I've gathered:

- Users have been able to successfully compile the model after changing the `leaky_relu` to `relu`, although accuracy may decrease. I know you've mention this, but I wanted to put this on the list for other users to reference.
- Secondly, I suspect that you are using `tf-nightly` or some newer tf version for your conversion? If so, I suggest downgrading to maybe tf2.2, some newer version of the same ops are not yet supported by the compiler.
- Try turning off `MLIR` converter also, released version of the `edgetpu_compiler` doesn't play well with `MLIR`

lmk if you found some success, would love to give this a shot also!
fyi: I got yolov4 converted but the architect only allows 1/962 ops to run on the edgetpu so it's a bummer no go.

Comment: I have changed to tf2.2 and used TOCO converter instead. Now I can't convert the model and the issue now is:


`<unknown>:0: error: failed while converting: 'main': Ops that can be supported by the flex runtime (enabled via setting the -emit-select-tf-ops flag): ResizeNearestNeighbor,ResizeNearestNeighbor.`

Comment: I have also tried on tf-nightly to turn off MLIR converter by set `experimental _new_ converter=False` but the result is the same. By looking on netron, I saw the model has been quantized and it was Toco converted

Comment: Hey, sorry, I think you'll need to train using tf2.2 also :/
Please take a look at this answer: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/147#issuecomment-644246990

Comment: For clarification, my suggestion is that creating and training of the model should also be done in tf2.2, not just tflite conversion.

Comment: I think quantize aware training is the solution for now :D

Comment: Hey, FYI, I found this: https://github.com/guichristmann/edge-tpu-tiny-yolo
It works out of the box with link to other repo for creating your own :)

Comment: I have implemented this, but the converter seems does not work well with darknet retrained weights. I have also contact the author, but there is no reply :D

Comment: Yeah, I've also tried the darknet weight with not good results. I think the authored retrained on the coco dataset, he has a canned model in his directory that seems to work very well: `python3 inference.py --edge_tpu --quant --model models/quant-coco-tiny-v3-relu_edgetpu.tflite --anchors cfg/tiny_yolo_anchors.txt --classes cfg/coco.names --cam`
I would absolutely look more into it if I get more bandwidth :)

Comment: I think so. That is why I contact him and he got me no response :(